# CMake does not generates MinGW makefile, but MSVS 2013

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64

I am trying to build simple console application using MinGW installation from here: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html. This package already contains GCC 4.9.2 and Boost 1.57. Creating simple file like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After that I doing following:

```
> pwd
/d/..../Boost-Accumulators
> mkdir build
> cd build
> pwd
/d/..../Boost-Accumulators/build
> cmake -g "MinGW Makefiles" ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/alp/Projects/Boost-Accumulators/build
```

After all I've got only MSVS projects/solution (I have versio 2013 installe also) for this app building. But I want to build it using MinGW installation.

How to achieve it?

**UPD**: cmake -**G** "MinGW Makefiles" .. - that is the correct command line.
One note I've found when executing it - I have `sh.exe` in my PATH - one in `MSYS` and one in `Git` directories. It is affects MinGW build so I renamed it so `sh1.exe` both and all works fine!

Comment: The generator option is uppercase: `-G`

Comment: @Angew oh thank you! Shame on my head!

Comment: You should either delete the question, or answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The generator option is uppercase: -G

@Angew